# Chartjs in Django, special characters in label not supported?

Tags: django, chart.js

I have some values passed to Chart.js but I found neither / nor - is supported. If the labels are harded coded as UK-aaa or N/A, it works fine. If it is passed as a varible which the project requires, UK or N (letters before the special characters will not recognized and no chart shows. Is there a workround on Javascript other than removing special characters in labels? Thanks.

```
var C3 = document.getElementById(canv3.getAttribute('id'));
             if (C3.getContext) {              
                if (C3.getContext) {
                        new Chart(document.getElementById(canv3.getAttribute('id')), {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: [{{res.21}},{{res.22}},{{res.23}}], //this is not supported if same value as below passed.
                            //labels: ['UK-aaa','N/A','N/A'],  //this is supported
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    backgroundColor: "rgba(35, 35, 0.5)",
                                    borderColor : "rgba(149, 62, 205, 1)",
                                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(62, 149, 205, 1)",
                                    data: [{{res.18}},{{res.19}},{{res.20}}] //numeric value
                                },
                            ]
                        },

        options: {
                responsive: false,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
                    });
                    }}
```

Comment: You surely need to put them in quotes. Even better, pass them as JSON.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]